# Geb: Check if an element is not present/displayed

Tags: geb

I want to check that a particular element is not displayed in Geb.

```
selectedClients { $(".selection") }
```

Here are several of the stuff I've tried so far: none working.

```
assertThat(module.selectedClients.not.displayed)

assertThat(module.selectedClients.displayed).isEqualTo(false)
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

To clear the ambiguity, what I was actually checking for here was the presence of child elements within the object. I was able to resolve this, using a size() check.

```
assertThat(module.selectedClients.size()).isEqualTo("0")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
assertThat(!module.selectedClients.displayed)
```

Comment: what is different between `displayed` and `isEmpty` . Can they check element is exist or not .

Comment: Displayed checks if the element is actually visible, not just in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating through each element and checking visibility

```
    module.selectedClients.each {
        assertThat(it.displayed).isEqualTo(false)
    }
```

I'm not too familiar with junit syntax :/

Comment: I edited the question for clarification. What I was checking for was the presence of child elements within the object. Anyway, this would work in a general case. Thanks :).

Answer (score -2):

Simply do this:

`if(elementName.size() ==1)` or not.